# GDMS (Grandstream) API issue when HTTP POST curl php

Tags: php, api, telephony

I'm trying to send a HTTP POST request through curl in php to the new Grandstream API and I'm getting the same error each time. I have to say I'm currently able to do GET requests successfully but the problems start when a body has to be send in POST.

```
$gdms_domain = "eu.gdms.cloud";
$timestamp = round(microtime(true)*1000);

$params_data = array(
        'access_token' => '*********',
        'client_id' => '*****',
        'client_secret' => '************',
        'timestamp' => $timestamp
);
$body_data = array(
        'pageSize' => "",
        'pageNum' => "",
        'order' => "",
        'type' => "",
        'orgId' => ""
);
$params = http_build_query($params_data);
$body = json_encode($body_data);
$signature = hash("sha256","&".$params."&");

$payload_data = array(
    'access_token' => $token,
    'signature' => $signature,
    'timestamp' => $timestamp
);
$payload = http_build_query($payload_data);

$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://'.$gdms_domain.'/oapi/v1.0.0/device/list'."?".$payload,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content_type: application/json"
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_error($ch)){
    echo 'Request Error:'.curl_error($ch);
}else{
    $response = json_decode($response);
    print_r($response);
    return $response;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

The error that is returned is:

```
(
[data] => 
[msg] => bad signature
[retCode] => 40003
)
```

The API documentation is in here [GDMS API](https://doc.grandstream.dev/GDMS-API/EN/#api-157061470296601000002). I tried to build the signature in both possible ways according to the docs and send the body in different ways.

Thank you

Comment: This is probably too late to help the OP, but lots of people have actually been having trouble with the GDMS API. I've been able to work with Grandstream to get some of their documentation improved and I've put together a simple SDK that can be used to use the API (or as a reference), if anyone else has similar struggles: https://github.com/InterLinked1/GDMS

Answer (score 1):

You should add the hashed body to the signature.

```
$body_signature  = hash("sha256",$body);
```

Then final signature should be

```
$signature = hash("sha256","&".$params."&".$body_signature."&");
```